# Can SSRS append new data to an existing file (Excel, google doc etc)

Tags: reporting-services

Question is basically as the title states. I have a report that exports a day's worth of data to excel each morning. Is it possible within the SSRS subscription environment to have that data append to the same excel file (or google doc etc) rather than create a new file each time (and without having to run more than a day's data at a time).

Comment: This is not a feature supported by the subscription service, however, there are many ways to concatenate the files after delivery.

Comment: Automatically from my end? The end user is not technically savvy and doesn't want to go through any complicated process.

Comment: If processing delay is a concern have you thought about caching the report or creating a snapshot covering a larger swath of data? The renderer will only render to a supported format, there is no merging support at that level.